# Вывод текста с бд для всех пользователей кроме одного SimplaCMS

Tags: php, smarty

В SimplaCMS я добавил в раздел группы пользователей, описание и обозвал его text_group.
Есть две группы пользователей id=2 и id=15, ну и конечно id=1(админский)

Вывожу в tpl так

```
{$group->text_group}
```

для group_id==2

А как для всех пользователей, даже если не реганный или админ, видели текст с group_id==15

???

UPD

В api пытался добавить group_text

```
function get_groups(/*group_discount*/$filter = array()/*/group_discount*/ )
  {
    /*group_discount*/
        $order = 'g.discount';
        $discount_filter = '';
        if (isset($filter['is_discount'])) {
            $discount_filter = $this->db->placehold('AND g.is_discount=?', intval($filter['is_discount']));
        }
        /*/group_discount*/
    
    /*group_visible*/
    $filter_for_visible = '';
    if (isset($filter['for_visible'])) {
        $filter_for_visible = $this->db->placehold('AND g.for_visible=?', intval($filter['for_visible']));
        }
    /*/group_visible*/          
    
    // Выбираем группы
    $query = $this->db->placehold("
    SELECT g.id, g.name, g.text_group, g.discount, g.is_discount, g.short_name, g.for_visible
        FROM __groups AS g
    WHERE 
    1 
    $discount_filter 
    $filter_for_visible         
        ORDER BY g.discount
    ");
    $this->db->query($query);
    return $this->db->results();
  } 
  
  function get_group($id)
  {
    // Выбираем группу
    $query = $this->db->placehold("SELECT * FROM __groups WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", $id);
    $this->db->query($query);
    $group = $this->db->result();

    return $group;
  }
  
    function get_group_text($id)
  {
    // Выбираем группу
    $query = $this->db->placehold("SELECT * FROM __groups WHERE id=15 LIMIT 1", $id);
    $this->db->query($query);
    $group = $this->db->result();

    return $group_text;
  }
```

Сама groupadmin.php

```
<?PHP
require_once('api/Simpla.php');

class GroupAdmin extends Simpla
{   
    public function fetch()
    {
        $group = new stdClass;
        if($this->request->method('post'))
        {
            $group->id = $this->request->post('id', 'integer');
            $group->name = $this->request->post('name');
            $group->text_group = $this->request->post('text_group');
            $group->discount = $this->request->post('discount');
                        /*group_discount*/
            $group->short_name = mb_substr($this->request->post('short_name'), 0, 10, $this->config->php_charset);
            $group->is_discount = (int)$this->request->post('is_discount', 'boolean');
            /*/group_discount*/
            /*group_visible*/
            $group->for_visible = $this->request->post('for_visible', 'boolean');
            /*/group_visible*/
    
            if(empty($group->id))
            {
                $group->id = $this->users->add_group($group);
                /*group_visible*/
                if ($group->for_visible) {
                    $this->products->alter_table_add_column_p(intval($group->id));
                }
                /*/group_visible*/
                /*group_discount*/
                if ($group->is_discount) {
                    $this->variants->alter_table_add_column_v(intval($group->id)); 
                }
                /*/group_discount*/
                $this->design->assign('message_success', 'added');
            }
            else
            {
                                /*group_visible*/
                $group_m = $this->users->get_group(intval($group->id));
                if ($group_m->for_visible !== $group->for_visible) {
                    if ($group->for_visible) {
                        $this->products->alter_table_add_column_p(intval($group->id));
                    } else {
                        $this->products->alter_table_drop_column_p(intval($group->id));
                    }
                }
                /*/group_visible*/
                                /*group_discount*/
                $group_m = $this->users->get_group(intval($group->id));
                if ($group_m->is_discount != $group->is_discount) {
                    if ($group->is_discount) {
                        $this->variants->alter_table_add_column_v(intval($group->id));
                    } else {
                        $this->variants->alter_table_drop_column_v(intval($group->id));
                    }
                }
                /*/group_discount*/
                $group->id = $this->users->update_group($group->id, $group);
                $this->design->assign('message_success', 'updated');
            }
            $group = $this->users->get_group(intval($group->id));
        }
        else
        {
            $id = $this->request->get('id', 'integer');
            if(!empty($id))
                $group = $this->users->get_group(intval($id));          
        }   

        if(!empty($group))
        {
            $this->design->assign('group', $group);         
        }
        
        return $this->design->fetch('group.tpl');
    }
    
}
```

выводить пытаюсь в cart.tpl

Comment: откуда вы получаете этот $group ? он привязан к текущему юзеру или откуда берется? Очевидно, если у вас нет под рукой списка групп и текстами, то для нереганного юзера надо вытащить дефолтное значение.

Comment: @teran добавил посмотрите пожалуйста